# Rescale rep graph on y-axis

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation-graph, stackexchange.com, network-profile

On the network profile rep graph, you can select a time period for the graph to zoom in.  That part is nice, but if you select a relatively narrow time strip the graph becomes stretched out, and part of this is because the y-axis isn't scaled for the selected time period.

Yeah, I know this isn't that important a feature, it's just something nice to have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SE.com's rep graph is rendered using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/), which doesn't seem to expose an option to "zoom in the x dimension, and then auto-scale the y-dimension". I did, however, just set the [zoomType](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart--zoomType) to `xy`, which allows you to zoom 2-dimensionally by clicking and drawing a rectangle. After playing around with it a bit,  I think I like it more this way.